# P.T. $\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)} +\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)} \ge \frac 32$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

> If $abc=1$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real. Prove that ,$\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)} +\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)} \ge \frac 32$.

I tried to multiply the LHS by $abc$ to make the relation homogeneous but......
There is a $3$ in the RHS ,So I applied AM-GM and found that it is enough to show that 
$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \le 8$ where $abc=1$.
I know it is a very well-known inequality but I couldn't answer it . Please help me.
[image: My calculations]

**Source:** It is derived from a question came in any Olympiad question (I cannot remember, now).
It is a good problem for the application of AM-GM or, Cauchy-Schartz.Jensen's inequality can also help.

Comment: Langrange maybe?

Comment: I don't know Lagrange.I think it can be done by basic inequalities

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the question in addition to your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: $$\begin{align} \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}
= \sum_{cyc} \frac{(a^{-1})^2}{a(b+c)}
\stackrel{(1)}{\ge} & \frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{-1}\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}{a(b+c)}}
= \frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^{-1}\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}{(c^{-1}+b^{-1})}}
= \frac12\sum_{cyc}a^{-1}\\ \stackrel{(2)}{\ge} & \frac32 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} = \frac32\end{align}$$
$(1)$ [Engel's form](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/) of Cauchy Schwarz, $(2)$ AM $\ge$ GM.

Comment: How did you get to the inequality $(x+y)(y+z)...$? Please explain how AM-GM helped here. Also, note that if the last inequality is sufficient to prove the result, then it follows from the cyclic equivalents of $a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$ by multiplying these and noting $abc = 1$.

Comment: @CarlMummert The question does include thoughts and attempts: could you clarify what exactly more is needed?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: the post lacks the more important information: the source and motivation of the problem.  The OP has not indicated why anyone would be interested in verifying the inequality at hand.

Comment: @achille hui Your solution is absolutely right. Thanks. I have found my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$a=\frac1x, \, b=\frac1y, \, c=\frac1z \implies xyz=1$$

$$\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)} +\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)} \ge \frac 32 \iff \frac{x^2}{y+z} +\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac 32$$

by [Jensen's Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jensen%27s_Inequality) with $f(x)=x^{-1}$ convex we have that

$$\frac{\frac{x^2}{y+z} +\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{x+y}}{x+y+z}=\frac{xf\left(\frac{y+z}x\right) +yf\left(\frac{x+z}y\right) +zf\left(\frac{x+y}z\right)}{x+y+z}\ge f\left(\frac{(y+z)+(x+z)+(x+y)}{x+y+z}\right)=\frac12 $$

and by AM-GM $x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}=3$.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi $\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}=\frac{x^3}{\frac{y+z}{yz}}=\frac{x^3yz}{y+z}=\frac{x^2}{y+z}$

Comment: You may use Engels form instead of Jensen's inequality!! But it is really a nice one

Comment: @SufaidSaleel Probably there are many others way! I like that very much.

Comment: Please tell me what do you mean by Lagrange.I don't know that. Please send me the link or tell me the full name of the theorem so that I can search it in Google

Comment: @SufaidSaleel Lagrange is  amethod suggested by dmtri in the comments, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 1):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2c^2}{a(b+c)}\geq\frac{(ab+ac+bc)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+c)}=$$
$$=\frac{(ab+ac+bc)^2}{2(ab+ac+bc)}=\frac{1}{2}(ab+ac+bc)\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=\frac{3}{2}.$$